The ALSA framework supports multiple DMA input
I am currently working on the digital microphone tuning for PDM interface, and each input channel of the PDM has a DMA. Currently, I need to enable ALSA to support multiple PDM DMA input channels. What should I do?
Modify the ALSA framework to support multi-channel DMA input.
